# How to add an outlook email address to a Microsoft 365 Family Account that has a Gmail Login

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

**Question**: How do you add an Outlook address to Microsoft 365 Family account that has a Gmail Login?

**Context**:
Someone has signed up for a Microsoft 365 Family account. They use a Gmail as their Microsoft Account login.

However, they would like to use the full suite of Microsoft services, including Outlook.

When they log in to Outlook web with their Microsoft account (e.g. using their gmail as the user and a password), then they get to an inbox, but that inbox seems to be unusable.

How does one convert or add an Outlook email to this Microsoft account or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

That mailbox (connected to .your MS account with Gmail login) has a different, automatically created email address which is very messy.

You can set up auto forwarding tho.
You can check that email address after getting to outlook.com and clicking on your profile picture (top-right), then mouseover the address.
[image]